# Get XML file, based on current date

Tags: javascript, xml, url, date

I am very new to parsing XML data with javascript, so please excuse me if my question is a bit simple.

I am parsing data from an XMl file with javascript using a standard xmlHTTPRequest. The format of the URL that I am pulling the XML data from is something like: "http://example.com/abcyymmdd-data.xml". The (yymmdd) portion of the url represents the date and the files are updated daily. I would like to insert a javascript code in the url in place of yymmdd so that a new XML file is parsed each day. How might I achieve this?

Thanks,
Carlos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the current date in `yymmdd` format like:

```
var d = new Date();
var date_string = 
    d.getFullYear().toString().substring(2) +
    (d.getMonth () < 9 ? "0" : "") + (d.getMonth() + 1) +
    (d.getDate() < 10 ? "0" : "") + d.getDate();
```

[Example at JS Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/uMNeR/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am able to format the date as you suggested, but still can't retrieve xml data when I plug-in the "date_string" var to the xml url. Here is how I entered it: **bold**var url = (location.toString().indexOf('file://') != -1) ? 'http://example.com/abc" + date_string + "-data.xml';**bold** I then called this var with **bold**xmlhttp.open(GET,url,true)**bold** Not sure where I am going wrong, but it is probably a simple error in m syntax.

Comment: @Carlos: Use `alert(url)` or [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see what your `url` contains.  Btw, you can use backticks \` to quote code in comments.

Comment: I finally got it to work. I had to use single quotes instead of double quotes to insert the '+date_string+' variable...thanks very much for your help. Here's a sample of my final code `code`var url = (location.toString().indexOf('file://') != -1) ? 'http://example.com/abc'+date_string+'-data.xml' : 'fcx'+date_string+'-data.xml';
 xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 if (xmlhttp != null) {
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
  xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true,);`code`

Answer (score 3):

First, to get today's date, use:

```
var today = new Date;
```

To get the components, use:

```
var date  = today.getDate();
var month = today.getMonth() + 1; // caveat, starts at 0
var year  = today.getFullYear();  // 4 numbers (e.g. 2011)
```

Now, you need it in the format `yymmdd`. So you need to remove the two first numbers from year, and prepend a `0` to date and month, if necessary.

```
function zeropad(number) {
    var str = number.toString(); // number to string

    return str.length === 1 // if length is 1
            ? '0' + str     // prepend a 0
            : str;          // otherwise return string without modification
}
```

And then:

```
var formatted = year.toString().substring(2) // only the string from the first two numbers and on
                 + zeropad(month)            // month with 0 prepended
                 + zeropad(date);            // date with 0 prepended
```

Then, in your XHR, use:

```
xhr.open("GET", "http://example.com/abc" + formatted + "-data.xml", true);
```

Comment: @pimvbd: Thanks for the quick response. I tried to insert your code, but I am unable to retrieve xml data via this method. It most-likely is an error on my part, because I am not sure of how to implement the code. The only difference I see may be causing problems is that I am using "xmlhttp.open(GET, url, true)" and the url is a var (i.e. "var url = (location.toString().indexOf('file://') != -1) ? 'http://example.com/abc110828-data.xml' : 'abc110828-data.xml';" This var is because I may want to store the xml locally so that the last download is available for offline use. Thanks, Carlos.

Comment: @Carlos: Try removig that `;` before `:` since the expression has not ended there yet.

Comment: @pimvdb: Sorry, the extra ; was a typo. It is not part of the code. I am still unable to retrieve xml data with this method.

Comment: @Carlos: Did you manage it without my code? I believe XHR does not work locally anyway. Try it on a server instead.

Comment: I finally got it to work! Your example was very helpful. I had to combine methods from your answer and the answer above from @Andomar. Also had to use single quotes and no space to plug in the date variable. Here's a sample of my final code `code`var url = (location.toString().indexOf('file://') != -1) ? 'http://example.com/abc'+date_string+'-data.xml' : 'fcx'+date_string+'-data.xml';
 xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 if (xmlhttp != null) {
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
  xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true,);`code`